# msp430 ask for updating firmware when sending program

Tags: msp430, code-composer

I'm using CSS to program an MSP430-f5529. The drivers of the chip are supposed to be installed as far as I cheked them on the administration field of my computer. 
The problem is that when I send a program from CSS to my chip it creates an error. The program starts saying that it has to update the firmware of the chip and after the actualization it gives me an error saying:
"Encountered a problem loading file C:\Users....\simple led blink.out
Could not open the file"
Can someone help me please.

Comment: MSP430: GEL: Encountered a problem loading file: C:\Users\Brais\workspace_v5_5\simple led blink\Debug\simple led blink.out Could not open file

Comment: This las one is the error that it gave us

Comment: Does your program compile?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it this morning it was a problem with the libraries that were not copied on CCS folder during the installation of texas instruments software. It's incredible that one company as texas instruments provides this horrible software to program their devices.